# bluetooth manager window is not opening in kali linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, blueman

my problem is Bluetooth manager windows not opening in Kali Linux

i started the Bluetooth service in Kali Linux
$ systemctl start Bluetooth.service

blue-man package is also installed

but when i open the Bluetooth manager, the window is not opening like it just opens and closes in a second

how to solve this issue

Comment: Is kali the right distro for you, you may be better finding a more mainstream distro? The devs regard it as for advanced users only. And remember, kali is not named after the hindu god.